# How to use CountDownTimer.cancel() in android with API <= 19

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I try to stop `CountDownTimer` with this code, but the method `this.cancel()` below only work on Android >= 5.0 , it doesn't work with Android verson lower and it 'll keep running . Can anyone help me ?

```
CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(10000,100) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long l) {
                    if(seekbar.getProgress() >= seekbar.getMax()){
                        this.cancel();
                    }
                    seekbar.setProgress(seekbar.getProgress() + 10);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    this.start();
                }
            }.start();
```

Comment: call `cancel` method on ref `countDownTimer `

Comment: countDownTimer's `cancel ()` is not depended on API version.

Comment: copy the sources of `CountDownTimer` from 5.0 and use them in your project

Comment: when i call `countDownTimer.cancel()` outside it can stop but i need use it inside :(

Comment: @pskink can you show me detail

Comment: just copy the sources of `CountDownTimer` from working android 5.0 to your project

Comment: I have this exact issue. cancel() works on all except older devices. Does anyone have a fix for this?